# GraphQL as an abstraction for a data modelling tool

Tags: graphql

I'm trying to think out loud here to understand if graphql is a likely candidate for my need.

We have a home-grown self servicing report creation tool. This is web-based. It starts with user selecting a particular report type.
The report type in itself is a base SQL query. In subsequent screens, one can select the required columns, filters, etc. As we The output of all these steps is a SQL query, which is then run on an Oracle database.

As you can see, there are lot of cons with this tool. It is tightly coupled with the Oracle OLTP tables. There are hundreds of tables.

Given the current data model, and the presence of many tables, I'm wondering if GraphQL would be the right approach to design a UI that could act like a "data explorer". If I could combine some of the closely related tables and abstract them via GraphQL into logical groups, I'm wondering if I could create a report out of them.

```
**Logical Group 1**
Table1
Table2
Table3
Table4
Table5

**Logical Group 2**
Table6
Table7
Table8
Table9
Table10
```

and so on..

Let's say, I want 2 columns from tables in Logical group 1 and 4 Columns from Logical Group 2, is this something that could be defined as a GraphQL object and retrieved to be either rendered on a screen or written to a file?

I think I'm trying to write a data modelling UI via GraphQL. Is this even a good candidate for such a need?

We have also been evaluating Looker as a possible data modelling layer. However, it seems like there could be some
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Without understanding your data better, it is hard to say for certain, but at first glance, this does not seem like a problem that is well suited to GraphQL.

GraphQL's strength is its ability to model + traverse a graph of data. It sounds to me like you are not so much traversing a continuous graph of data as cherry picking tables from a DB. It certainly is possible, but there may be a good deal of friction since this was not its intended design.

The litmus test I would use is the following two questions:

- Can you imagine your problem mapping well to a REST API?
- Does your API get consumed by performance sensitive clients?

If so, then GraphQL may serve your needs well, if not you may want to look at something like https://grpc.io/

Comment: In terms of data, consider it to be a transaction based system in normalized form. Depending on what the client would like to see in the report, there could be a possibility of a complex graph traversal. In my mental model, I'm trying to look at graphql as something that will help the report creator to choose the data they want from these groups. I expect the UI to figure out the connections between these groups.